# Смена таймзоны полей в queryset для вывода в api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-model, django-filter

Есть таблица в которой есть поля `id`, `name`, `date_created`.
Мне нужно выводить данные из этой таблицы с изменением таймзоны для пользователя в зависимости от той какая у них. Как это лучше реализовать ?
Пример:

```
Таблица в БД
id | name  | date_created
---|------ | ------
1  | New1  | 2022-05-13 10:00:00
2  | New2  | 2022-05-13 12:00:00
```

Вывод в `API` по Москве:

```py
[{"id": 1, "name": "New1", "date_created": 2022-05-13 10:00:00}, 
 {"id": 2, "name": "New2", "date_created": 2022-05-13 12:00:00}]
```

Вывод в `API` по Тюмени:

```py
[{"id": 1, "name": "New1", "date_created": 2022-05-13 12:00:00}, 
 {"id": 2, "name": "New2", "date_created": 2022-05-13 14:00:00}]
```

Comment: Во-первых, все даты в базе стоит по возможности хранить в таймзоне UTC. Во-вторых, а почему менять таймзону должны именно вы? Отдавайте тот же самый UTC, а клиенты пусть сами разбираются, в каких таймзонах они живут, и сами конвертируют UTC-время как им надо — почему бы не сделать так?

Comment: У меня в зависимости от этих дат строится математика, я поля по которым строится математика не указал.

Comment: Математику тем более стоит делать в UTC, а не в Москве и не в Тюмени, наверное?